# android bitmap translate up and down

Tags: android, bitmap

hello im new in android programming, i wanna ask how to translate bitmap up and down with float input ?
here is my code :

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.horizonsx);
bmpWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
bmpHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
drawMatrix();

private void drawMatrix(){

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setTranslate(0,10);


  Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0,0, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, matrix, true);

 imageviewrot.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
imageviewrot.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER); ///THIS WAS THE KEY LINE
```

}

but failed to translate the bitmap up with value of 10. How i can do it ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make use of `sprite`s...where a sprite will hold ur bitmap and then we can make `translation/rotation` on sprite

take some tips from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469031/rotate-a-sprite-in-game-android?rq=1)

Comment: if i manipulate the xml code with translation , it works , but how manipulate xml code in java ?

Comment: im sory ,still dont understand the answer of that reference, is there any other reference?

Comment: wht are the things apart from a bitmap u want to show on a page...is dat only bitmap that is there to view or anything else...try to be clear with ur need (not mentioning the code what u have written) so dat i can help....coz in cases ur req will be something and to fulfill u might be using a wrong direction... so let me know wt u want to show on the screen....

Comment: i have horizon bitmap , i want to make flight indicator app, so i want to translate up and down that horizon bitmap as i change the y axis on that bitmap from streaming input data, thats what i do, please help me

Comment: the horizon bitmap is an atlas rit (or else what is it)?... and u want to have a plane to show on the atlas... so u will have two bitmaps...one atlas and one plane rit?

Comment: thats right, i already put the plane with rotation , now i need a horizon that can move up and down.. i set the matrix.settranslate not works

Comment: then look no further, google 'sprite tutorials in android' bye